# What is the difference in testing file upload and download with FTP request and HTTP requests in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

which is the actual way to test performance of upload and download files using JMeter tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP and FTP protocol are totally different, if your application supports both - you need to load test both methods as they are handled differently on the server side. Your load test needs to simulate what real users are/will be doing so check your application requirements prior to building the test plan.

- For simulating HTTP uploads and downloads you need to use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
- For simulating FTP uploads and downloads - go for [FTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request) sampler. FTP protocol provides some more ways of files and folders manipulation, i.e. moving, deleting, listing contents, etc. so you may also need to perform these operations using [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) libraries and [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), check out [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) guide for comprehensive explanation and example code snippets

Comment: Just want to confirm that real user is going to download/upload using browser (HTTP request) then what is the case where FTP will be getting used by real user.

Comment: If real user won't be using FTP for files operations - you should not be load testing this protocol, I would recommend to solely focus on HTTP implementation, see [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for instructions on how to set up JMeter for mimicking files uploads and downloads.